# wp.data.dispatch( 'core' ) returns null

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am following the tutorial "Build your first block" and have a folder structure representing the scaffold created by the `npx @wordpress/create-block@latest` command.

Using it as my starting point, I'm trying to retrieve the WordPress core store to add an entity, but I keep getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEntities')".

Here is the whole `src/index.js` file with the code I have added starting at `import { dispatch } from '@wordpress/data';` (scaffold comments removed for brevity).

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

import './style.scss';

import Edit from './edit';
import metadata from './block.json';

registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,
} );

import { dispatch } from '@wordpress/data';

dispatch( 'core' ).addEntities( [
    {
        name: 'programs',
        kind: 'amilia/v1',
        baseURL: 'amilia/v1/programs',
    },
] );
```

It appears `dispatch( 'core' )` returns `null` and I have no idea why. Should I be calling it in a different place?